# In Java, should each query be in a separate thread?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

If an application is blocking until a query returns a response, doesn't it make sense to execute queries on a thread pool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if you expect to perform work during that period, otherwise there's no sense doing it. A nice way to do it is to have your API return a `Future`. Something like:

```
interface QueryService {
   public FutureTask<QueryResult> query(Query q);
}

FutureTask<QueryResult> res = query(..);
// do work
res.get(); // blocks until result is in
```

Of course, you should typically submit your `Callables` or `Runnables` to an `ExecutorService`  .

Comment: Thanks this answer is sufficient as there is another thread on this topic.